# Dependency inject for Entity Framework Core in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I cannot seem to be able to get my context while using Dependency injection for EFCore in an Azure Function .NET 6.

```
namespace func_vend
{
    public class VendProcess
    {
        private readonly AppDBContext _context;
        public VendProcess(AppDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        [FunctionName("VendProcess")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            if (req.Method == HttpMethods.Post)
            {
                string reqbody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vend>(reqbody);
                _context.Vends.Add(product);
```

It stops and errors at the _content.Vends.Add(product) line by saying "An object reference is required for the non-static field". No matter what I try - I cannot seem to get it working.

Here is my startup code for the azure function that sets the DI.

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(func_vend.Startup))]

    namespace func_vend
    {
        public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
        {
            public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
            {
                // this is where Jason adds the keyvault stuff once i get the connection string good once its added
                var KeyVaultURL = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVaultURL"));
                var secretclient = new SecretClient(KeyVaultURL, new DefaultAzureCredential());
                //var cs = secretclient.GetSecret("sql").Value.Value;
                var cs = "server=servername.mysql.database.azure.com;database=dbheat;username=blah;password=yeahman";
                builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(cs));
    
                
    
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my AppDBContext :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace func_vend
{
    public class AppDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Vend> Vends { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the vend class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace func_vend
{
    public class Vend
    {
        
    public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string pan { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide full code and other classes

Comment: @RithwikBojja - full code provided and thank you.

Comment: You variable is non-static AppDbContext while the function is static. Don't you get design time error in VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick fix, all you have to do is remove the *static* keyword from your Run method.

When the Run method (or any method) in an Azure Function is defined as static, it cannot directly use instance variables or instance fields because static methods belong to the class itself rather than any particular instance of the class.